# how to plot some data that is in two scales in gnulpot

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot, scale

I want to plot some data that is in two scales.

for 1 < X < 20 , Y is between 0 and 1 and

for 20 < X < 100 Y is between 1 and 20

normal plot has this result: [image]

and as you see the carve between 0 and 20 is hidden!
how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a logarithmic scale

```
set logscale y
```